# how to add OR constraints to exclude query in django?

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following exclude that brings back all of books that have had transactions in the past two minutes.  I want to add another constraint that says only if from a series of stores.

In SQL it would be where location_id = 1 or location_id = 2 or location_id = 3

Books have a location_id

How can I apply that to the below query?

```
transaction_window = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=-2)

ts = Book.objects.exclude(book_id__in = Status.objects
                             .filter(transaction_time__gte=transaction_window)
                             .values_list('book_id', flat=True))
```

Comment: `Book.objects.exclude(status__transaction_time__gte=transaction_window)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just want `location__in=(1, 2, 3)`

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Q object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects). They're built-in to django and allow more complex lookups.

Answer (score 0):

From your code assuming `Book` model has field `book_id` and `Status` has also field `book_id` and this field are just plain `IntegerField` or similar.

```
from django.db.models import Q

transaction_window = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=2)

statuses = Status.objects.filter(transaction_time__gte=transaction_window)
ts = Book.objects.filter(~Q(book__id__in=statuses)
                         | ~Q(location_id__in=(1, 2, 3)))
```

If my guess about your models is correct.